# Meteor publish with extra fields

Tags: javascript, meteor

I publish user data on server including date of birth field

```
Meteor.publish('sharedUserData', function(uId) {
  return Meteor.users.find(uId, {
    fields: {'dateOfBirth': 1}
  });
})
```

I want to calculate 'Age' (e.g age = 30) on server and return it to client within this publication. How can I implement it? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by providing [`transform`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find) option to the `find` method:

```
Meteor.publish('sharedUserData', function(uid) {
  return Meteor.users.find({
    _id: uid,
  }, {
    fields: {
      dob: 1
    },
    transform(doc) {
      const {
        dob,
      } = doc;

      doc.age = calculateAge(dob);

      return doc;
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems what I need but the problem is that I can't run this transform method (I used the code but transform wasn't called while publishing)
From the other hand I defined _transform method for Meteor.users and it worked fine.